# The “rearrangement” of integrals

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis

This question comes from Fleming's book "Functions of Several Variables", which is a little bit like the rearrangement of convergent series:

> Let $f$ be continuous on an open set $D$.Assume that the integrals of $f^+$ and $f^-$ over $D$ both diverge to $+\infty $.Show that given any number $l$ here is a sequence of compact sets $K_1\subset K_2\subset \cdots $ such that $D=K_1\cup K_2\cup \cdots $ and $lim_{n\to \infty}{\int_{K_n} fdV}=l$.

The following is my thought:

Since $\int_D f^+ dV=+\infty$, there exists compact set $K_{11}\subset D$ such that $$\int_{K_{11}} f^+ dV>l+1$$ Similarly,there exists compact set $K_{12}\subset D$ such that $$
\int_{K_{12}}{f^-dV}>\int_{K_{11}}{f^+}dV-\left( l+1 \right) 
$$

We can remove the part on which $f^+>0$ from $K_{12}$(This part can be open by the continuity of $f^+$),and then $K_{12}$ is still compact.The similar procedure should be acted on $K_{11}$.And then let $K_1=K_{11}\cup K_{12}$,we have $$
\int_{K_1}{f}dV=\int_{K_1}{f^+}dV-\int_{K_1}{f^-}dV<l+1
$$
By using the approach similar to the above process,we can get $K_1\subset K_2\subset \cdots$ with $\int_{K_n} fdV<l+\frac{1}{n}$ while $n$ is odd;$>l-\frac{1}{n}$ while $n$ is even.

- However, it still cannot show that $lim_{n\to \infty}\cdots =l$ and $\bigcup K_i =D$.

Comment: This is jut a suggestion, I have not checked the details. For $r>0$, define  $K_r=\{x:|x|\leq r\}\cap\{x:d(x,D^c)\geq\frac{1}{r}\}$. The $K_r$'s are compact sets contained in $D$ with non empty interior. Define the functions $\phi_+(r)=\int_{K_r}f_+$  and $\phi_-(r)=\int_{K_t}f_-$. These are continuous functions (that requires a proof).

Comment: @OliverDiaz What you said is right.But how to show $lim_{r\to \infty}\phi_+-\phi_-=l&.Would you give me more details? Thank you very much!

Comment: Edit: It is just an interplay between choosing a values for which say $\phi_+$ overshots $2\ell$ plus something small, and $\phi_=(r)$ undershoots $\ell$ by something small. than take the difference.I am trying to be able to use the intermediate value theorem here. Also, at each step, one can cut out from compact sets the part where $f_+>0$ or %f_->0$ as you did in your construction.  Again, it is a suggestion and I don't know if it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sketch of Proof.** It is possible to create two non-decreasing families $\{ K^+_r \}_{r\in[1,\infty)}$ and $\{ K^-_r \}_{r\in[1,\infty)}$ of compact subsets of $D$ such that

1. $\cup_{r\geq 1}K^+_r = \{f \geq 0\}$ and $\cup_{r\geq 1}K^-_r = \{f \leq 0\}$, and
2. $r \mapsto \int_{K^+_r} f^+(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$ and $r \mapsto \int_{K^-_r} f^-(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$ are continuous.

Then by using the intermediate value theorem, we may choose $(s_n)$ and $(r_n)$ such that $s_n, r_n \to \infty$ and $\int_{K^+_{s_n} \cup K^-_{r_n}} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = l$. Then the choice $K_n = K^+_{s_n} \cup K^-_{r_n}$ will work.

---

**Proof.** Choose a sequence of compact subsets $K^0_1 \subset K^0_2 \subset K^0_3 \subset \dots $ of $D$ with $D = \cup_{n\geq 1} K^0_n$. Then, for each choice of sign $\varepsilon \in \{+, -\}$, define the family $\{ K^\varepsilon_{r} \}_{r \in [1, \infty)}$ as follows:

- Set $K^\varepsilon_1 = K^0_1 \cap \{ \varepsilon f \geq 0\} $.
- Next, if $n \in \{1, 2, \dots\}$ and $K^\varepsilon_n$ is defined, then for $r \in (0, 1]$,
  $$K^\varepsilon_{n+r} := K^\varepsilon_n \cup \Bigl( K^0_{n+1} \cap \{ \varepsilon f \geq 0\} \cap \overline{B(0, nr)} \Bigr). $$

Also, we define

$$ \phi^\varepsilon(r) := \int_{K^\varepsilon_r} f^\varepsilon(x) \, \mathrm{d}x $$

Then it is easy to check that

1. $K^\varepsilon_r$ is compact for each $ r \geq 1$. This is because each $K^\varepsilon_r$ is a closed subset of $K^0_{\lceil r \rceil}$. In particular, $\phi^\varepsilon$ is finite.
2. $\phi^\varepsilon$ is non-decreasing, since $K^\varepsilon_s \subseteq K^\varepsilon_r$ for any $1 \leq s \leq r$.
3. $\lim_{r\to\infty} \phi^\varepsilon(r) = \infty$. This follows from $\cup_{r \geq 1} K^\varepsilon_r = \{ \varepsilon f \geq 0\}$ and the assumption.
4. $\phi^\varepsilon$ is continuous. Indeed, suppose $n \leq s \leq r \leq n+1$. Then the construction gives the bound
   $$ 0 \leq \phi^\varepsilon(r) - \phi^\varepsilon(s) \leq M |B(0,1)| \bigl( (n(r-n))^d - (n(s-n))^d \bigr), $$
   where $d$ is the dimension of $D$, $M = \sup_{K_{n+1}} |f|$, and $|B(0,1)|$ is the measure of the unit ball.
5. For any $s, r \geq 1$, we have $ f \geq 0$ on $K^+_s$ and $f \leq 0$ on $K^-_r$. So,
   $$ \int_{K^+_s \cup K^-_r} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = \phi^+(s) - \phi^-(r). $$

Now let $l $ be arbitrary. Then we may choose two increasing sequences $(s_n)$ and $(r_n)$ such that $s_n, r_n \to \infty$ and $\phi^+(s_n) - \phi^-(r_n) = \ell$. Finally, we may set $(K_n)$ as

$$ K_n = K^+_{s_n} \cup K^-_{r_n}. $$